# Errors when trying to use a vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, stl

At the top of my file *main.h* I have:

```
#include <vector>

class Blah
{
  public:
    Blah(){}
    ~Blah(){}
  protected:
    vector<int> someVector;
  public:
    //methods
};
```

When I try to compile, the vector declaration line gives the errors:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

I can't figure out what's causing this. Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `error: no template named 'vector'; did you mean 'std::vector'?` ... I'm *quickly* warming up to the error messages clang produces...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `vector` class is part of the `std` namespace. You need to replace your declaration with `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: +1 Completely correct! - but *please* don't encourage `using namespace std`  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann I've seen it in major libraries, but duly noted.

Comment: Really?  I'm honestly curious now... I've only seen it as something that students have to *unlearn*.

Comment: @izuriel - "major libraries" is not the same as "well-designed libraries".

Comment: @PeteBecker I never said "well-designed libraries" either (and corrected the answer) :P

Comment: @izuriel - I see: you were pointing out other places where you've seen it. Still, I'll leave the comment alone, as a caution.

Answer (score 5):

It's in the `std` namespace:

`std::vector<int> someVector;`

Answer (score 3):

[vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is part of the *std namespace* and so you need to add `std::` to your declaration:

```
std::vector<int> someVector;
```

Since the suggestion was made in another answers, I want to also discourage the use of `using namespace std` since it is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,

> std::vector someVector;

Always try to use,

> using namespace std;

Because it will help you not to type 'std::' again and again, and it is not considered a good practice.